# How many apprentices did the Emperor have?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, sith, darth-sidious

Pretty straight forward question:
**How many total apprentices did the Emperor have?**

Bonus if which apprentices overlapped and broke the Rule of 2 is listed.

I can think of

- Darth Maul
- Count Dooku
- Darth Vader

And Maul and Dooku overlapped.

Comment: Well he didn't really break the rule of two, he literally abolished it. The rule of two served it's purpose prior to launching his plan, but it was no longer necessary after. The novel "Plagueis" has all the info you need. Maul was Sidious 1st apprentice btw.

Comment: @Hatandboots, so are you saying that when we see Maul show up in Episode 1, Duku wasn't an apprentice of Sidious already?

Comment: The exact point of Dooku's turn to the dark side is a little fuzzy for me, but Sidious had already had Maul as an assassin apprentice for years before that. I believe the point Dooku became an apprentice of Sidous is after Sidious killed his master, which happened about half way through episode 1.

Comment: Are you looking for canon only or Legends?

Comment: Bonus if any of them had an apprentice of thier own while still acting as apprentice to the emperor.

Comment: @Null, either/or, ideally you could provide both and label them for those who want to know both.

Comment: @ryan I added the Legends tag then.

Comment: Downvoters care to explain themselves?

Comment: How will you give bonus?

Comment: Dukoo and Maul didn't overlapped

Comment: @hatandaboots he killed his master right before he got word of Maul's death

Comment: Dukoo and Maul didn't overlap, Maul died long before Dukoo became Sidious' apprentice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Full list based on Wookieepedia, Quora and extensive Googling of other sources. "{}" shows canon sources for the information about apprenticeship.

- [Darth Maul](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Maul) { *Episiode I* }
- [Vergere](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Vergere) { *Legacy of the Force: Betrayal* }
- [Darth Tyranus/Count Dooku](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dooku) { *Episode II* }
- [Garth Ezzar](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Garth_Ezzar) { *[Destruction RPG](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Destruction_%28Living_Force_adventure%29)* }
- [Darth Vader/Anakin Skywalker](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Anakin_Skywalker) { *Episode III - VI* }
- [Ferus Olin](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ferus_Olin) (informal apprentice) { *The Last of the Jedi: Secret Weapon* }
- [Lumiya](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lumiya) { *Jedi vs. Sith: The Essential Guide to the Force* }
- Luke Skywalker when Palpatine was in clone body { *Dark Empire 5: Emperor Reborn* }

Please note that aside from Maul; Tyranus and Vader, none of these are Disney Canon - they are all Legends canon only.

All 3 Disney canon apprentices had apprentices of their own (Maul: Savage Opress; Tyranus: [a whole bunch](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dooku); Vader: [a whole bunch](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Anakin_Skywalker) but IIRC none are Disney canon). It's not clear if Savage Opress strictly violated the Rule of 2 as they didn't meet until after Maul was de-apprenticed by Obi-Wan's lightsaber.

---

He also had a bunch of people he trained who were not strictly speaking "Apprentices", such as (incomplete list of examples)

- Emperor's Hands (e.g. [Mara Jade](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mara_Jade_Skywalker))
- Prophet [Cronal](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Cronal) etc.
- Adepts who weren't apprentices, e.g. an [unknown Nikto](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Unidentified_Nikto_dark_side_adept)  { *Book of Sith: Secrets from the Dark Side* }

Comment: What about general Grievous? He was Tyranus' apprentice, but by chain of command also Emperors'?

Comment: @Zikato - 1. he wasn't a Sith. 2. He wasn't even Force Sensitive. 3. he wasn't anyone's apprentice. Other than that, he fits :)

Comment: Lumiya was Vader's apprentice not Palpatine